# Can QGIS remember the state of open tables?

Tags: qgis

Is there an option to choose while saving a QGIS project,to save the state of the table views and their location on the screen?

[image]

I am on 3.6.3-Noosa

Comment: I don't think so. I can see how that would be useful, though. I recommend making a [feature request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues) (maybe wait a few days and see if you get an answer here first).